# Post raw html string on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I'm trying to implement tinymce to my laravel project.

```
<div class="mt-5">
      <label for="crud-form-2" class="form-label">Description</label>
      <textarea id="editor"  name="innerText"></textarea>
   </div>


tinymce.init({
            selector: '#editor',
            plugins: [
                "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen",
                "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media",
                "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks",
            ],
            toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        });
```

But when I check what send to my controller, laravel strips html tags. As an example if I fill my tinymce text area with;

```
<p>Some description</p>
```

It passes to controller as 'Some description'. It ignores my html tags.

[Devtools payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a22Zd.png)

Comment: You need to use [{!!  !!} to show unescaped data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data)

Comment: I'm not retrieving html string data from my database. I'm trying get an input value which holds html string on my controller and save it to my database.

Comment: How are you checking what is being sent to the controller? Is it being shown in the browser, or are you logging it with `Log::info`? If it's shown in the browser, look at the source code, the browser is probably actually just using the tags.

Comment: Via dd($request->all()), and also checking my database records.

Comment: There is nothing know in laravel that manipulates inputs (except for empty one to null). You mostly checked what you got from input with blade echo`{{ }}` and those do strip tags. try `dd(request()->innerText)` in your controller and add the result to your question.

Comment: Also, when submitting the data, check your network tab in the browser to check on the payload, maybe it's not something in laravel that changes the input but something in tinymce plugin.

Comment: dd($request->innerText) returns 'Some description' without html tags. Also I changed my code to use Ajax when I submit the form. On network tab, I'm sending `<p>Some description</p>` but when I use $request->innerText, it returns without html tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's called entity encoding. TinyMCE did that by default. You need more options for raw html. From [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#entity_encoding) it says:

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  entity_encoding: 'raw'
});
```

They also explain more about valid_elements which is useful if you need some  tags inside your tinyMCE editor

Comment: Thanks for help but I'm getting html value from textarea without problem. I added a screenshot from payload.

Comment: i built something similar to you, laravel didnt sanitize tags. the only different thing is that im not using ajax. You can try with traditional post request and show the result to check that laravel wont sanitize input, esp on textarea

Answer (score 0):

I make ajax post request like this:

```
let text_content = $.trim(tinymce.get(textarea_id).getContent({format : 'text'}));
let raw_content = tinymce.get(textarea_id).getContent({format : 'raw'});

$.ajax({
    'url': url,
    'type': 'post',
    'data': {'changes': (text_content) ? encodeURIComponent(raw_content) : text_content}
});
```

The `text_content` will prevent `data-mce-bogus="1"` to be passed to your controller if you leave textarea/tinymce blank. So if `text_content` is not blank you pass `encodeURIComponent(raw_content)`.

Then in your controller you do `urldecode($inputs['changes'])` which can save the changes as raw html.